# How to establish bidirectional communication between two iOS apps

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have to establish bidirectional communication between my iOS apps. The data that have to be exchanged were text and json. Is it possible with the file sharing feature of app extension? If so, is there a sample that is available to guide through the steps? What are the pre-requisites to create the group id for app group?

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to speak to another bundle, this is more of an Android behaviour.

Your only way is to use an intermediate server, and that could be a complete book.

What I suggest, is having your files/data stored online, and build both your apps to be able to read and write on that server.

Comment: Thank you. I have explored on the app groups entitlements in iOS where apps which use the same group id could share files / data which they save to that common space. It is not direct communication but the data shared by one app could be used by the other.